# Kivy: Adding a label and image to a button for a reusable widget

Tags: python, kivy

I am making a reusable widget in kivy that contains a couple of child widgets. One of those child widgets is a button that I want to have a text centered on the button, and a small icon aligned on the right of the button. I am trying to achieve it by adding a StackLayout to the button, but because the button is a widget, the stacklayout's position isn't inside the button. Since I am going to reuse the widget in multiple places, I don't see how I can make the position relative to the parent widget.

With the current example, the image isn't displayed at all and the text is displayed at the bottom of the app.

[image: label in wrong position]

A complete minimal working example is on https://github.com/dolfandringa/kivy_playground/blob/master/button_label_image/

But this is the relevant code for my widget:

```
from pathlib import Path

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout

ICON = Path(__file__).parent.resolve() / 'caret-down-solid.png'


class MyWidget(StackLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.height = '32dp'
        self.button = Button()
        button_layout = StackLayout()
        self.button.add_widget(button_layout)
        label1 = Label(text="[color=000000]text1[/color]",
                       markup=True)

        icon = Image(source=str(ICON), size=(16, 16))
        button_layout.add_widget(label1)
        button_layout.add_widget(icon)
        self.add_widget(self.button)
```

and this is how the widget is being used in a sample app kv file:

```
#:import MyWidget widgets
GridLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    cols: 1
    Button:
        text: "hello"
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
    MyWidget:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: root.width*0.5
    Button:
        text: "hello2"
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the widget py file like below to achieve your target:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: '32dp'
    Button:
        text: 'text1'
        icon_size: 16, 16
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'caret-down-solid.png'
                size: self.icon_size
                pos: self.pos[0] + self.width - self.icon_size[0], self.pos[1] + self.icon_size[1] / 2
""")

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

Here a custom property `icon_size` is defined for `Button` and used it to adjust the size and position of the icon inside `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option in addition to the one from @amras is to use a RelativeLayout like this:

```
class MyWidget(StackLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.height = '32dp'
        self.button = Button(
            text="text1",
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
            size_hint=(1, 1)
        )
        button_layout = RelativeLayout()
        self.add_widget(button_layout)
        button_layout.add_widget(self.button)
        icon = Image(source=str(ICON), size=(16, 16), size_hint=(None, None))
        icon.reload()
        icon.pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.95, 'center_y': 0.5}
        button_layout.add_widget(icon)
```